# ASP.Net MVC ActionFilterAttributes ordering Global vs Local

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if there was an order to the execution of ActionFilterAttribute attributes. I am guessing the local ones (an ActionFilterAttribute defined on the Action of a Controller) are executing in the order they are defined on the Action.

However does any one no whether Global filters are applied before local ones or vice versa? Also if there is a defined order and not just arbitary is it consistent across version of Mvc?

Thanks in advance
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of contributing factors which dictate the order in which action filter attributes are run, from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx#filterorder)

> Within each filter type, the Order value specifies the run order. Within each filter type and order, the Scope enumeration value specifies the order for filters. This enumeration defines the following filter scope values (in the order in which they run):
>
> 1. First
> 2. Global
> 3. Controller
> 4. Action
> 5. Last

Also, your assumption

> I am guessing the local ones (an ActionFilterAttribute defined on the Action of a Controller) are executing in the order they are defined on the Action

Is incorrect, there is no defined order for filters with no order/scope defined

> The execution order of filters that have the same type, order, and scope is undefined.

If you care about the order they are executed then you should specify this using the [Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.order%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property.

Comment: That's great to know. I always assumed that filters are executed in orders they are registered in the FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters

Answer (score 1):

Order of filters is something like this:

1. Global OnActionExecuting
2. Local controller scope filter OnActionExecuting
3. Local action scope filter OnActionExecuting
4. Action invokation
5. Local action scope filter OnActionExecuted
6. Local controller scope filter OnActionExecuted
7. Global OnActionExecuted

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is what I was after - however Andrew's answer more complete which is why I marked his answer as the chosen answer.

Comment: Just re-read my comment and realised I said Andrew's answer when I meant James'